# Use XSLT to add value from one element to another

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source XML file as follows:

```
<section name="Test" code="" type="Table" fundid="15" subtype="SOI1" style="" xmlns="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4">
  <table xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" accountperiod="2014-07-31" accountperiodtype="0" code="I2" name="Holdings" fundid="15" type="" cols="2">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" />
    <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" />
    <tbody>
      <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="621" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="Caption" value="Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies" display="always">Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="16.6" display="always">16.6</datapoint>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="623" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Literal" subtype="Custom" name="All Others*" value="All Others*" display="always">All Others*</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="1.5" display="always">[~PONT]1.5[#~PONT]</datapoint>     (Line A)
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr type="otherassets" level="1" itemtype="otherassets" hierarchykey="858">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Literal" subtype="Custom" name="Other Assets" value="Other Assets" display="always">Other Assets</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="0.1" display="always">[~PONT]0.1[#~PONT]</datapoint>     (Line B)
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

What I would like to do is take the 0.1 between the [~PONT] and [#~PONT] tags from (Line B) and add it to the 1.5 between the [~PONT] and [#~PONT] tags on (Line A), then suppress the  node containing (Line B). The resultant XML should look like this:

```
<section name="Test" code="" type="Table" fundid="15" subtype="SOI1" style="" xmlns="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4">
  <table xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" accountperiod="2014-07-31" accountperiodtype="0" code="I2" name="Holdings" fundid="15" type="" cols="2">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" />
    <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" />
    <tbody>
      <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="621" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="Caption" value="Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies" display="always">Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="16.6" display="always">16.6</datapoint>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="623" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Literal" subtype="Custom" name="All Others*" value="All Others*" display="always">All Others*</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="1.6" display="always">[~PONT]1.6[#~PONT]</datapoint>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

I know I can isolate the numeric values by using something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Value1" select="substring-before(substring-after(string(.),'[~PONT]'),'[#~PONT]')"/>
```

Unfortunately that's about all I do know. I apologise if this question seems rather vague, it's kind of difficult to explain, so please ask me for any more details. Thanks in advance for any advice. I am using XSLT version 1 by the way.

Comment: What exactly identifies "Line A" and "Line B"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this matches the requirements as they are a bit unspecific, but following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tab="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/tab:datapoint[@value='All Others*']]/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(.) + 
          sum(//tab:tr[@type='otherassets']/tab:td[2]/tab:datapoint/@value)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>  
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/tab:datapoint[@value='All Others*']]/text()">
    <xsl:text>[~PONT]</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(./parent::*/@value) + sum(//tab:tr[@type='otherassets']/tab:td[2]/tab:datapoint/@value)"/>
    <xsl:text>[#~PONT]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tab:tr[@type='otherassets']"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to the input XML in the question produces the output

```
<section xmlns="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4" name="Test" code="" type="Table" fundid="15" subtype="SOI1" style="">
 <table xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" accountperiod="2014-07-31" accountperiodtype="0" code="I2" name="Holdings" fundid="15" type="" cols="2">
  <colspec colnum="1" colname="1"></colspec>
  <colspec colnum="2" colname="2"></colspec>
  <tbody>
     <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="621" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
           <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="Caption" value="Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies" display="always">Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
           <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="16.6" display="always">16.6</datapoint>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="623" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
           <datapoint type="Literal" subtype="Custom" name="All Others*" value="All Others*" display="always">All Others*</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
           <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="1.6" display="always">[~PONT]1.6[#~PONT]</datapoint>     (Line A)

        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

For this transformation I added as example namespace in the XSLT for the additional namespace `xmlns="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4"` of the input XML

```
xmlns:tab="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4"
```

The template matching

```
<xsl:template match="tab:tr[@type='otherassets']"/>
```

is empty and removes this `tr`.

The template matching

```
<xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[parent::*/preceding-sibling::*
                    /tab:datapoint[@value='All Others*']]/@value">
```

changes the value of the `value` attribute to the sum of this value and the value of the `datapoint` of the `tr[@type='otherassets']` :

```
<xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(.) + 
          sum(//tab:tr[@type='otherassets']/tab:td[2]/tab:datapoint/@value)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

To change the text, the template matching the `text()` of this `tr`

```
<xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[parent::*/preceding-sibling::*
                    /tab:datapoint[@value='All Others*']]/text()">
```

doesn't use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` as suggested in the question, but instead the values of the `value` attributes of the datapoints to get the sum of both values:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(./parent::*/@value) + 
       sum(//tab:tr[@type='otherassets']/tab:td[2]/tab:datapoint/@value)"/>
```

This is based on the assumption that the value of the `value` attribute is the same as the value in the text between the `[~PONT][#~PONT]`.

**Update:** For the question in the comment how this could be adjusted in case the text in the match patterns wouldn't be hardcoded but parameters:

Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tab="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
 omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="otherRemove" select="'otherassets'"/>
  <xsl:param name="otherKeep" select="'All Others*'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[@name='PercentOfNetAssets']/@value">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="parent::tab:datapoint/parent::tab:td
                /preceding-sibling::*/tab:datapoint[@value=$otherKeep]">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(.) + 
           sum(//tab:tr[@type=$otherRemove]/tab:td[2]/tab:datapoint/@value)"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[@name='PercentOfNetAssets']/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="parent::tab:datapoint/parent::tab:td
                /preceding-sibling::*/tab:datapoint[@value=$otherKeep]">
        <xsl:text>[~PONT]</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(./parent::*/@value) + 
             sum(//tab:tr[@type=$otherRemove]/tab:td[2]/tab:datapoint/@value)"/>
        <xsl:text>[#~PONT]</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tab:tr">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@type=$otherRemove"/>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

produces the same result.

As adjustments the two parameters

```
  <xsl:param name="otherRemove" select="'otherassets'"/>
  <xsl:param name="otherKeep" select="'All Others*'"/>
```

have been added.
To remove the row, now the template matching all `tr`

```
<xsl:template match="tab:tr">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@type=$otherRemove"/>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

copies all `tr` if they don't have the `@type` attribute value `$otherRemove` which is `otherassets`.
The templates matching `text()` and `@value` are adjusted in the same way:

```
<xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[@name='PercentOfNetAssets']/text()">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="tab:datapoint[@name='PercentOfNetAssets']/@value">
```

Both templates check in an `<xsl:choose>`

```
<xsl:when test="parent::tab:datapoint/parent::tab:td
          /preceding-sibling::*/tab:datapoint[@value=$otherKeep]">
```

for the same condition that was the hardcoded template match pattern of the first version as `$otherKeep` is `All Others*`, adjusts the values of matching elements and copies all other `text()` and `@value` elements.

Comment: Good that you updated `datapoint/@value` in addition to the element text. I missed that.  sum() is also a nice touch.   (+1)

Comment: Just as an aside though, how would it be possible to do this when instead of hard coding the text 'otherassets' and 'All Other*', the texts would be in the form of two parameters. I know template match won't let me use a variable or parameter in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @FordPrefect141 Glad I was able to be of help and just updated my answer with an adjusted version for the additional question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with the identity transform so that by default all nodes are
   copied over to the output.
2. Then add an override to suppress the `tr` you no longer want.  In
   the example below, I keyed off of `@itemtype='otherassets'`.
3. Then add an override for the `datapoint` to receive the tally.  In
   the example below, I keyed off of `categorykey`, `itemtype`, and
   `colname`.  You may wish to adapt/generalize per your full example,
   but this criteria works with your sample input and should give you a
   feel for what's needed.

**This XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:b="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b:tr[@categorykey='623']/b:td[@colname='2']/b:datapoint">
    <xsl:variable name="v1"
                  select="substring-before(substring-after(string(.),'[~PONT]'),'[#~PONT]')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="otherdp"
                  select="../../../b:tr[@itemtype='otherassets']/b:td[@colname='2']/b:datapoint"/>
    <xsl:variable name="v2"
                  select="substring-before(substring-after(string($otherdp),'[~PONT]'),'[#~PONT]')"/>
    <xsl:copy>[~PONT]<xsl:value-of select="$v1 + $v2"/>[#~PONT]</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b:tr[@itemtype='otherassets']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Yields the desired XML output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section xmlns="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4" name="Test" code="" type="Table" fundid="15" subtype="SOI1" style="">
  <table xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" accountperiod="2014-07-31" accountperiodtype="0" code="I2" name="Holdings" fundid="15" type="" cols="2">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1"/>
    <colspec colnum="2" colname="2"/>
    <tbody>
      <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="621" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="Caption" value="Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies" display="always">Health Care Equipment &amp; Supplies</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint type="Regular" subtype="" name="PercentOfNetAssets" value="16.6" display="always">16.6</datapoint>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr type="categoryhead" level="1" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="623" hierarchykey="989">
        <td colname="1">
          <datapoint type="Literal" subtype="Custom" name="All Others*" value="All Others*" display="always">All Others*</datapoint>
        </td>
        <td colname="2">
          <datapoint>[~PONT]1.6[#~PONT]</datapoint>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```